# Can we use quilt to push/add to local git repository?

Tags: linux, git, quilt

Can we use quilt to push/add to local git repository?
If yes, kindly help me to specify the commands and any URL/link will be of immense help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to apply a quilt patch series, use `git quiltimport` as suggested by Luke Girvin.

If you want to use a workflow similar to quilt on git, I suggest you look at [stgit](http://www.procode.org/stgit/), [guilt](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jsipek/guilt/)([guilt gitweb](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/jsipek/guilt.git;a=summary)), or [topgit](http://repo.or.cz/w/topgit.git)

Answer (score 1):

"git-quiltimport - Applies a quilt patchset onto the current branch":

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-quiltimport.html